# .htaccess is ignored when using ScriptAliasMatch

Tags: git, apache, .htaccess, apache-config

I want to prepare a few GIT repositories available via http/https. I read here and there and learnt about [git-http-backend](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html), I followed the tutorials and managed to get everything to work. I can clone the repositories providing crentials specified in my htpasswd file (let's assume user1 and user2 for now) and push the changes back.

My repos are in **/var/www/git**, and so is gitweb.

**etc/httpd/conf.d/git.conf** :

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL

ScriptAliasMatch \
    "(?x)^/git/(.*/(HEAD | \
                    info/refs | \
                    objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
                             [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
                             pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
                    git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
    /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/$1

ScriptAlias /git /var/www/git/gitweb.cgi

<Location /git>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Basic Auth"
    AuthBasicProvider file ldap

    # LDAP
    AuthzLdapAuthoritative Off
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://[...]/CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=example,DC=com?sAMAccountName"
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=example,DC=com"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword Password11

    # FILE 
    AuthUserFile /var/www/htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /var/www/git.groups
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I clone the repository with

```
git clone http://localhost/git/gitrepo
Username for 'http://localhost/git/gitrepo': user1
Password for 'http://user1@localhost': XXXXX
```

The problem is that I'm trying to setup repository-based authorization, I want only a group of users to be able to access each repository. I figured out using .htaccess files would be the perfect solution (no need to restart the server), so I put a simple .htaccess in my repository's directory /var/www/git/gitrepo :

```
Require User test2
```

Theoretically, cloning / pushing changes using test1 should be disallowed, but it is still working. It turns out that the .htaccess is ignored, because no matter what I put there I can clone the repository if I'm authenticated.

I think that there might be a problem with the **ScriptAliasMatch**, maybe all the handling goes to git-http-backend exec and it doesn't go back to Apache since it redirected all the traffic? I'm a rather newbie in Apache, so it might be a simple story, but please - help ! :)

**Update 1**: Yes, AllowOverride is set to "All" in the main config for /var/www/git:

```
<Directory "/var/www/git">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: I wonder if there's anything that can be done here (I guess I'll join the mailing list), but I just wanted to say I switched to Gitolite and it works like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Your /var/www/git directory is outside the normal Web document tree.
That is a good thing, but it means that only the git-http-backend will
actually access this directory, not the web server, as such any .htaccess
file does not get read.

You either need to have authentication in the server conf area, so it
authenticates the URL, or as a wrapper where the git-http-backend program is located.

It is possible to have multiple GIT repositories on a single server, though very very few documents detail how to do this.